# group by one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know how to describe exactly the question title, but you can imagine the flowing:
I have a table and I want to select the distinct data

```
    A    B    C
   Cat   10   False
   Dog   25   True
   Dog   20   False
   Cat   5    False
```

when I use group by for A column and the result will be:

```
    A    B    C
   Cat   5    False
   Dog   20   False
```

Is it possile to make the result like this in MySQL:

```
    A    B    C
   Cat   10   False
         5    False
   Dog   25   True
         20   False
```

or any suggest that the table return me an array like:

```
Array(
       [Cat]=>Array(
                     [0]=> Array(
                                   [0]=>10
                                   [1]=>False
                                ) 
                     [1]=> Array(
                                   [0]=>5
                                   [1]=>False
                                )
                   )
       [Dog]=>Array(
                     [0]=> Array(
                                   [0]=>25
                                   [1]=>True
                                ) 
                     [1]=> Array(
                                   [0]=>20
                                   [1]=>False
                                )
                   )
     )
```

Comment: Just order by column A if you want all results.

Comment: `ORDER BY A` ? It does exactly what you described, but the `A` values are repeated

Comment: Are you literally asking for the value of A to only be output once (with empty strings in subsequent rows)?  That's more a formatting issue, which would be better handled in PHP.  Otherwise, yeah, just order by A.

Comment: I can you group by but I dont want the column A value repeated, or any ideas to handle this in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the next row column value matches with the previous row column value, you have to memorize previous row value to not show it again in the next row.

**Example**:

```
select 
    case when @prev != ( @curr := A ) then ( @prev := @curr ) else '' end as A
  , B, C
from( 
    select * from tbl_soq24465988 
    order by 1 asc, 2 desc
) sorted_table
, ( select @prev := '', @curr := '' ) initializer
;
```

**Output**:

```
+------+------+-------+
| A    | B    | C     |
+------+------+-------+
| Cat  |   10 | False |
|      |    5 | False |
| Dog  |   25 | True  |
|      |   20 | False |
+------+------+-------+
```

***Demo @*** [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff49/1)